# Typescript: Is it possible to stub a declared function for a unit test?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, sinon, rollupjs

For context, I'm writing typescript that gets compiled into javascript, is bundled with rollup, then called by a framework. This framework provides a library for me in the global scope. It's a function that looks like this:

```
    fun({
      prop1: number,
      ...
    });
```

I don't want to include this library into my bundled JavaScript because it's already provided by the framework. I think that could introduce lots of weird bugs if the version of the library in my code is different from the framework's. In theory, I think it would be less error-prone and simpler to just use the library that's provided by the framework.

I've done a *little* research, and I think the `declare` keyword is just for this purpose. So I put this in the same file I call `fun`:

```
export declare function fun(input: unknown): void;
```

Now my code compiles, but I haven't figured out a way of unit testing my production code. If I call the code that calls `fun`, jasmine complains that the function doesn't exist: `ReferenceError: fun is not defined`

I understand why this error is happening, but I have no idea how to work around it. I tried using sinon to stub `fun`, but it had a similar complaint about `fun` not existing when I ran my test in Jasmine.

I've come up with a workaround that I hate: I wrapped the call to `fun` in an `if` statement so the test skips the call to `fun`.

I want to know if there is some way to stub `fun` so I can execute code that calls it and confirm that the correct properties are being passed in. *Alternatively, is there a way I can write a fake version of `fun` and exclude it from the transpiled javascript, so it's `stub`able for testing, but doesn't exist in production? Given the way modules work, I don't think this is an option. But I'm open to all sorts of ideas, which is why I bring it up.*

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me. If there is a better/easier way, I'd like to know it.

```js
    // in some file (you must have an import/export in it or else it won't compile
    declare global {
      interface Window {
        fun: (input: unknown) => void;
      }
    }
    
    // in the test
      beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
        window.anime = sandbox.stub();
      });
    
      afterEach(() => {
        window.anime = ... // Optional. Put it back the way I found it
      });
    
    // somewhere in a test
       expect((window.fun as SinonStub).callCount).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```